# WPF MVVM StackPanel dynamic children type

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a list of properties that have a value and a type, and depending on the type, various controls should be added to stackpanel. ie - for text TextBox should be used, for double - some sort of numericupdown control. Can this be implemented with MVVM? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ItemsControl` with implicitly applied `DataTemplates` (add them to `Resources`, set `DataType` only (use `x:Type`)).

`ItemsControl` because the `StackPanel` is the last step that only allows UI elements as children, `ItemsControl` accepts data as items.